# Why doesn't this MySQL UPDATE command work?

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried everything I know. I know it's not a database connection thing because I am running this in the same way I INSERT data and it's in the same function file.

```
function update($name, email, $id) {
    $in = "UPDATE tablename 
           SET (name, email) VALUES('$name', '$email')  
           WHERE id = '$id'";

    mysql_query($in);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `id` is a string and not int?

Comment: @xbonez both string and int can be wrapped in single/double quotes.

Comment: @bsdnoobz: Interesting. Wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 6):

You SQL should be like this

```
$in = "UPDATE tablename
       SET name='$name', email='$email'
       WHERE id='$id'";
```

And as noted by @Falcon, you missed a `$` in your function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Your function

```
function update($name, email, $id) {
```

says email and inside is using $email. Change it to

```
function update($name, $email, $id) {
```

and check

Answer (score 0):

try

```
update table_name
set
col1 = val1
col2 = val2
..........where id = $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE tablename 
           SET name='$name',email='$email'
           WHERE id = '$id'
```

Note: Make sure you sanitize the input.

Comment: what is different in your answer from question

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble look closer :X